# all Images getting pixeled in JQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am using Jquery animation to make a pic grow and change her top, When i am using changing the height and width all the pictures are getting pixeled till the animation stop.
Is there a solution for this issue?

```
$( "#"+id+"" ).animate({
        top: -261,
        opacity:1,
        width:251,
        height:180
    }, 500, function() {
    });
```

You can see the issue in here: http://jsfiddle.net/h3atk/2/

Press the first pic of Jordan.

Comment: What are the dimensions, in pixels, of the image?

Comment: I added jsfiddle link

Comment: Just an idea. Have two images: one small and one large. Have the large image placed in the red area with "opacity:0". Then scale up the small image untill it's same size as the large. Last, quickly fade out the small image and fade in the large image.